# Django's is_ajax() request works during development but breaks in production due to "undefined responseJSON"

Tags: ajax, django

During development, I have an ajax method that works--it executes, posts to the backend, my Django view checks if `is_ajax()`, then `return JsonResponse()`.

Back on the frontend, I dig into `responseJSON` to get my object.

In a production environment, there is apparently no `responseJSON`.

Why?

Here's my ajax method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $myForm = $('.ajax-public-toggle-form')
    $myForm.change(function(event){
        var $formData = $(this).serialize()
        var $endpoint = $myForm.attr('data-url')
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: $endpoint,
            data: $formData,
            success: handleFormSuccess,
            error: handleFormError,
        })
    })

    function handleFormSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // no need to do anything here
        console.log(data)
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(jqXHR)
    }

    function handleFormError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // on error, reset form. raise validationerror
        $('#public_toggle_form_errors').text(jqXHR["responseJSON"]["public"]);
        $('#public_toggle_form_errors').show();
        console.log(jqXHR)
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(errorThrown)
        $myForm[0].reset(); // reset form data

        // console.log(errors)
    }
})
```

So I can still console.log(jqxhr) but it won't include the `responseJSON` object like it does during development.

This is the Django view:

```
class AjaxView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                if self.request.user.profile.public:
                    data = {
                        'message': "Allow button click"
                    }
                    return JsonResponse(data)
                else:
                    data = {
                        'error': "ERRO HERE",
                        'message': "EORR MESG"
                    }
                    return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
            else:
                data = {
                    'message': "LOG IN"
                }
                return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
```

The console will first output:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST https://paira.herokuapp.com/profile/public_toggle 403 (Forbidden)
```

then:

```
project.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'public' of undefined
    at Object.handleFormError [as error]
```

'public' referring to:

```
function handleFormError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // on error, reset form. raise validationerror
        $('#public_toggle_form_errors').text(jqXHR["responseJSON"]["public"]);
```

The actual `jqXHR` response will have something like:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (e)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (e)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (e)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (e)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
"<!DOCTYPE html>↵↵↵<html lang="en" class="fontawesome-i2svg-pending">↵↵  <head>↵    <meta charset="utf-8">↵    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">↵    <title>Forbidden (403)</title>↵    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">↵    <meta name="description" content="">↵    <meta name="author" content="">↵    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">↵↵↵    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->↵    <!--[if lt IE 9]>↵      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>↵    <![endif]-->↵↵    ↵    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap 4 beta CSS -->↵    ↵    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">↵↵↵    <!-- Your stuff: Third-party CSS libraries go here -->↵    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />↵↵↵    <!-- This file stores project-specific CSS -->↵    <link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">↵    ↵    ↵↵    ↵↵  </head>↵↵  <body>↵    ↵↵↵<div class="">↵  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">↵    <a class="navbar-brand ml-3" href="/">Parup</a>↵    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">↵      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>↵    </button>↵↵↵    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">↵      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-5 align-items-center">↵↵        ↵          <li class="nav-item">↵            <a id="sign-up-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/signup/">Sign Up</a>↵          </li>↵          <li class="nav-item">↵            <a id="log-in-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/login/">Sign In</a>↵          </li>↵        ↵      </ul>↵    </div>↵  </nav>↵↵</div>↵↵    <div class="container pt-5 mt-5 mb-5">↵↵      ↵↵      ↵<h1>Forbidden (403)</h1>↵↵<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>↵↵↵↵    </div> <!-- /container -->↵↵    ↵        <div class="container-fluid footer mt-5 mb-2">↵          ↵<hr class="col-md-2" />↵<div class="row">↵    <div class="col-md-12">↵        I am the footer now↵↵    </div>↵</div>↵<div class="row h-100 footer-links">↵    <div class="col-md-12">↵        <p>ABOUT&nbsp&nbspCONTACT&nbsp&nbspTERMS&nbsp&nbspPRIVACY&nbsp&nbspBLOG</p>↵    </div>↵</div>↵        </div>↵    ↵    ↵↵    <!-- Le javascript↵    ================================================== -->↵    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->↵↵    ↵↵↵<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>↵<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>↵<!-- Required by Bootstrap v4 beta -->↵<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwApKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>↵<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>↵↵<!-- Your stuff: Third-party javascript libraries go here -->↵↵↵<script src="/static/js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>↵<script src="/static/js/reconnecting-websocket.min.js"></script>↵<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>↵↵↵↵↵↵↵<script src="/static/notifications/notify.js"></script>↵↵<script>↵        notify_badge_class='live_notify_badge';↵        notify_menu_class='live_notify_list';↵        notify_api_url='/inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/';↵        notify_fetch_count='10';↵        notify_unread_url='/inbox/notifications/unread/';↵        notify_mark_all_unread_url='/inbox/notifications/mark-all-as-read/';↵        notify_refresh_period=5000;↵    register_notifier(fill_notification_list);register_notifier( fill_notification_badge);</script>↵↵<!-- place project specific Javascript in this file -->↵<script src="/static/js/project.js"></script>↵↵<script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>↵↵↵↵<script type="text/javascript">↵    function getCookie(name) {↵        var cookieValue = null;↵        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {↵            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');↵            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {↵                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);↵                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?↵                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {↵                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));↵                    break;↵                }↵            }↵        }↵        return cookieValue;↵    }↵↵    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');↵↵    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {↵        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection↵        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));↵    }↵    $.ajaxSetup({↵        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {↵            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {↵                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);↵            }↵        }↵    });↵</script>↵↵↵    ↵    ↵  </body>↵</html>↵↵"
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (e,t)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
403
statusCode
:
ƒ (e)
statusText
:
"Forbidden"
then
:
ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__
:
Object
```

EDIT:  I am sending CSRF separately like this in a js.html:

```
{# CSRF #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- place project specific Javascript in this file -->
<script src="{% static 'js/project.js' %}"></script>
```

My original AJAX code is in project.js. The script file coming after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, server returns status code 403 FORBIDDEN. I guess you should include CSRF token to your ajax request. You can read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Does not explain why it works locally. I am sending csrf separately in another js file

Comment: Edit: csrf was definitely the issue. structure of my imports was off.